# How to use the content from a txt file as variable in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, hashicorp

I have a var_file.txt which contains several inputs listed, e.g.

```
dog
cat
bird
.
.
.
elephant
```

Is it possible to use that content to pass it to a variable in Terraform and use it as a list content for the Variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about an input variable for a child module then you can use the `file` function inside your `module` block to load the content of the file and pass it into the variable:

```
module "example" {
  source = "../example"

  argument = file("${path.module}/example.txt")
}
```

---

If you want to pass this into an input variable in your *root* module then the situation is quite different, because the values for root modules are being assigned from outside Terraform and so the solution to this will be in whatever software you are using to run Terraform, rather than within Terraform itself.

For example, if you are running Terraform using a shell script on a Unix system then you could potentially use one of the answers to [Pass contents of file as argument to bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393351/pass-contents-of-file-as-argument-to-bash-script):

```
terraform apply -var=example="$(<example.txt)"
```

If you want to pass plain text in this way then you should make sure to declare the input variable as `type = string` so that Terraform will know to interpret this argument as raw text. Some other type constraints will cause Terraform to try to parse the argument as an expression, which would be invalid here because your file does not contain Terraform expression syntax.